# Apache PDFBox and CodenameOne Desktop app

Tags: java, pdfbox, codenameone

I have a CodenameOne project which is mostly done, I need to integrate the desktop version with PDFBox. I am trying to open a document and render pages to images which I display in the application.

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFonts(PDResources.java:213)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.getFonts(PDFStreamEngine.java:607)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetTextFont.process(SetTextFont.java:59)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:557)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:801)
    at co.za.gingetsuryuu.pdfreader.PDFInterfaceImpl$1.run(PDFInterfaceImpl.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFonts(PDResources.java:213)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.getFonts(PDFStreamEngine.java:607)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetTextFont.process(SetTextFont.java:59)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:557)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:801)
    at co.za.gingetsuryuu.pdfreader.PDFInterfaceImpl$1.run(PDFInterfaceImpl.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFonts(PDResources.java:213)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.getFonts(PDFStreamEngine.java:607)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetTextFont.process(SetTextFont.java:59)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:557)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:801)
    at co.za.gingetsuryuu.pdfreader.PDFInterfaceImpl$1.run(PDFInterfaceImpl.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm at a total loss. I have checked that the libraries are included, it manages to render one or two of the pages, but no more than that. I've even checked that the function does exist, and it does.

Comment: What version of pdfbox do you use? What JRE version? This looks as if you're doing multiple threads. Did you try in a single thread?

Comment: 1.8 JRE and 1.8.8 pdfbox

Comment: Which versions of the PDFBox dependencies have you included?

Comment: fontbox 1.8.8, jempbox 1.8.8 xmpbox 1.8.8 commons-logging-1.2

Comment: that looks ok. But you seem to already have identified the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the way Codename One does the build process. By including the jar files in the result project and making them load higher in the jar load order than the app.jar file, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you place the jars of the PDF box API under the native/javase folder? If not the jar won't be sent to the build server and won't be packaged as part of the application.

Comment: I did. I have found the problem though.

Comment: @gindrskvy Then please either answer the question yourself if it could help others, or delete the question. Oops, I see you did. Please press the green checkmark, if available.